# How do I create an array and map over it to simplify my code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to improve my code according to some feedbacks of a reviewer of a course I'm studying.

So, I have this part of my code:

```
function Home(props) {
  const [, setShowSearchPage] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="list-books">
      <div className="list-books-title">
        <h1>MyReads</h1>
      </div>

      <div className="list-books-content">
        <div>
          <div className="bookshelf">
            <h2 className="bookshelf-title">Currently Reading</h2>

            <div className="bookshelf-books">
              <ol className="books-grid">
                {props.books
                  .filter(book => book.shelf === 'currentlyReading')
                  .map(book => (
                    <li key={book.id}>
                      <Book
                        book={book}
                        changeShelf={props.changeShelf}
                        actualShelf="currentlyReading"
                      />
                    </li>
                  ))}
              </ol>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="bookshelf">
            <h2 className="bookshelf-title">Want to Read</h2>

            <div className="bookshelf-books">
              <ol className="books-grid">
                {props.books
                  .filter(book => book.shelf === 'wantToRead')
                  .map(book => (
                    <li key={book.id}>
                      <Book
                        book={book}
                        changeShelf={props.changeShelf}
                        actualShelf="wantToRead"
                      />
                    </li>
                  ))}
              </ol>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="bookshelf">
            <h2 className="bookshelf-title">Read</h2>

            <div className="bookshelf-books">
              <ol className="books-grid">
                {props.books
                  .filter(book => book.shelf === 'read')
                  .map(book => (
                    <li key={book.id}>
                      <Book
                        book={book}
                        changeShelf={props.changeShelf}
                        actualShelf="read"
                      />
                    </li>
                  ))}
              </ol>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My question is:

Is there a stylish form for me to create an array of shelves info (the shelves are 'Current Reading', 'Want to Read' and 'Read') such as I could map over it and generate a block of code for each shelf, in order to avoid repeating the same code?

Comment: Thanks for editing my code, @Emile Bergeron. I'll be more careful in the next time I post a code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a ton of ways to refactor what you have, but here's what I think you're looking for:

```
function Home({books, changeShelf}) {
  const [, setShowSearchPage] = useState(false)
  const shelves = {
    currentlyReading: 'Currently Reading',
    wantToRead: 'Want to Read',
    read: 'Read',
  }

  return (
    <div className="list-books">
      <div className="list-books-title">
        <h1>MyReads</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="list-books-content">
        <div>
          {Object.keys(shelves).map(shelf => (
            <div className="bookshelf">
              <h2 className="bookshelf-title">{shelves[shelf]}</h2>
              <div className="bookshelf-books">
                <ol className="books-grid">
                  {books
                    .filter(book => book.shelf === shelf)
                    .map(book => (
                      <li key={book.id}>
                        <Book
                          book={book}
                          changeShelf={changeShelf}
                          actualShelf={shelf}
                        />
                      </li>
                    ))}
                </ol>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define render functions for not repeating same Code multiple times and it is easier to read

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const propTypes = {};
const defaultProps = {};

function Component(props) {
  const [, setShowSearchPage] = useState(false);

  const renderBook = (book) => (
    <li key={book.id}>
      <Book book={book} changeShelf={props.changeShelf}     actualShelf="currentlyReading" />
    </li>
  );
  const renderBookShelf = (books, title) => (
      <div className="bookshelf">
        <h2 className="bookshelf-title">{title}</h2>

        <div className="bookshelf-books">
          <ol className="books-grid">{books.map(renderBook)}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  return (
    <div className="list-books">
      <div className="list-books-title">
        <h1>MyReads</h1>
      </div>

      <div className="list-books-content">
        <div>
           {renderBookShelf(props.books.filter((book) => book.shelf === 'currentlyReading'), 'Currently Reading')}
           {renderBookShelf(props.books.filter((book) => book.shelf === 'wantToRead'), 'Want to Read')}
           {renderBookShelf(props.books.filter((book) => book.shelf === 'read'), 'Read')}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
Component.propTypes = propTypes;
Component.defaultProps = defaultProps;
export default Component;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, @duc mai. I've tested the solution, but the code has got a little instable unstable and the shelves that appear in the main page are showing the same shelves ("Currently Reading", "Currently Reading", Currently Reading"), not what it was supposed to appear ("Currently Reading", "Want to Read", "Read"). I think I'll have to study your code and try to improve.

Comment: I just fixed my code, forgot to read books from parameters :). Can you try again?

Comment: Thanks again, @duc mai. Another issue: why do you are using propTypes? Appear to me here that propTypes has a duplicate declaration.

Comment: duplication of propTypes? I dont think so. the reason to use propTypes because I usually follow react airbnb rules where demands for propTypes

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on a similar problem last year while working on NodeJS and Express. 
You can use [HTML tables](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) rather than lists. 
For populating the table, refer [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38393375/8307541)

Comment: Hi, @Raghu Raj Rai. I've seen the answer you've indicated me. It seems to me in some of the answers they were using JavaScript in the old syntax. Couldn't it have be maybe a more "ES6 solution"? Or maybe is this the best one?

Comment: @jose-renato-m, I can't think of any other way than this cause in any way, you'll have to use an iterator for rendering the elements.

Comment: You're suggesting HTML strings in a React question, OP's code works but he's asking for help to refactor, this is not answering the question at all.